# Validating that input is either list or list of lists of singular elemenents

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x

Is there any quick way of validating whether a list is in this format:

```
[a,b,c,...]
or
[[a,b,c...],[x,e,w,...],...]
```

but not

```
[[[a],[b],[c]...],[[x],[e],[w],...],...]
```

or anything similar

```
[[a,b,[e],f...],[x,e,w,...],...]
```

Essentially either a list of single elements, or a list of lists which contain single elements, but not a list of lists of lists or even more nested..

I've tried checking the second case with something like:

```
all(isinstance(elem, list) for elem in v)
```

But this won't work in my case

Comment: First, check whether all elements are of the same type. If so, and the common type is a list, check if any element of these lists is a list itself. That's all.

Comment: what about an empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine `not any()` and `all()` with `or`:

```
flat = lambda l: not any(isinstance(e, list) for e in l)
if flat(v) or all(isinstance(e, list) and flat(e) for e in v):
```

This short circuits and the whole is only true if either *none* of the elements in `v` are lists or *all* of them are flat lists.

Demo:

```
>>> def flat_or_singular(v):
...     flat = lambda l: not any(isinstance(e, list) for e in l)
...     return flat(v) or all(isinstance(e, list) and flat(e) for e in v)
... 
>>> tests = [
...     ['a', 'b', 'c'],
...     [['a' ,'b', 'c'], ['x', 'e', 'w']],
...     [[['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['x'], ['e'], ['w']]],
...     [['a', 'b', ['e'], 'f'], ['x', 'e', 'w']],
... ]
>>> for test in tests:
...     print('{}: {}'.format(flat_or_singular(test), test))
... 
True: ['a', 'b', 'c']
True: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'e', 'w']]
False: [[['a'], ['b'], ['c']], [['x'], ['e'], ['w']]]
False: [['a', 'b', ['e'], 'f'], ['x', 'e', 'w']]
```